# What is the shortcut key to always open a file on the left / right pane in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode13

In earlier versions of Xcode, I could consistently open a file either in the left or right window depending on whether I press `alt / option` when I click on the file.

In the current version (13.0), depending on which is the currently "active" pane, pressing `alt/option` and clicking causes a file to be opened in the other pane, meaning sometimes it opens on the right, and other times on the left, depending on which pane was originally active.

Is there a shortcut key, so that I can always open a file in the right pane, or left pane, regardless of which is the active pane ?

Comment: What are these right and left windows you're talking about?

Comment: Ah so you mean panes, not windows. Everyplace you just said window you need to say pane instead.

Comment: So the way I solve this is by using the Destination Chooser.  It lets me pick the left pane, the right pane, or a new pane, all using just the keyboard.

Comment: I assure you only the keyboard is involved.

Comment: It is ok... I have found the solution to go back to the 'old ways' :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://betterprogramming.pub/mastering-the-assistant-editor-in-xcode-11-4c26bdcd673 I have found `the way` :

[image: Menu Image]

Just go to preferences -> Navigation and change the settings to use primary editor instead of focused editor.